# Position of Seaborn heatmap annotations in cells

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The annotations in a Seaborn heatmap are centered in the middle of each cell by default.
Is it possible to move the annotations to "top left".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good idea may be to use the annotations from the heatmap, which are produces by the `annot=True` argument and later shift them half a pixel width upwards and half a pixel width left. 
In order for this shifted position to be the top left corner of the text itself, the `ha` and `va` keyword arguments need to set as `annot_kws`. 
The shift itself can be done using a translation transform.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.transforms

data = np.random.randint(100, size=(5,5))
akws = {"ha": 'left',"va": 'top'}
ax = sns.heatmap(data,  annot=True, annot_kws=akws)

for t in ax.texts:
    trans = t.get_transform()
    offs = matplotlib.transforms.ScaledTranslation(-0.48, 0.48,
                    matplotlib.transforms.IdentityTransform())
    t.set_transform( offs + trans )

plt.show()
```

[image]

The behaviour is a bit counterintuitive as `+0.48` in the transform shifts the label upwards (against the direction of the axes). This behaviour seems to be corrected in seaborn version 0.8; for plots in seaborn 0.8 or higher use the more intuitive transform

```
offs = matplotlib.transforms.ScaledTranslation(-0.48, -0.48,
                    matplotlib.transforms.IdentityTransform())
```

Comment: This is the correct answer in my opinion... I will just wait a few hours before accepting it. Again you helped me just perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: To get the displayed behavior I believe the first 2 arguments to ScaledTranslation should both be negative.

Comment: @NasaGeek The question asks for "top left". To obtain that, you need `~(-0.5,+0.5)`. If you use both negative (`~(-0.5,-0.5)`), the annotaton will be at the "bottom left" and additionally `"va": 'bottom'` , which is not what the question asks for.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Then I can only assume something has changed with matplotlib or seaborn. On mpl 2.0.2 and seaborn 0.8.0 your exact code shifts the annotations down and to the left, into the adjacent cell.

Comment: @NasaGeek  
Something must have changed in the seaborn update to 0.8 in the heatmap code. I updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/commit/7588d536d6e64e964df6a32472c07e6754daf988 likely culprit

Answer (score 3):

You can use `annot_kws` of seaborn and set vertical (va) and horizontal (ha) alignments like here (sometimes it works bad):

```
...
annot_kws = {"ha": 'left',"va": 'top'}
ax = sns.heatmap(data, annot=True, annot_kws=annot_kws)
...
```

[image]

Another way put labels manually like here:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

data = np.random.randint(100, size=(5,5))
ax = sns.heatmap(data)

# put labels manually
for y in range(data.shape[0]):
    for x in range(data.shape[1]):
        plt.text(x, y+1, '%d' % data[data.shape[0] - y - 1, x],
         ha='left',va='top', color='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

For more information and to understand text layout (why 1st example works bad?) in matplotlib read this topic: http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html

Comment: The heatmap annotations are placed at the `x,y` positions of the `xticks` and `yticks`. By default, the annotations are centred on the tick locations. All you are doing by setting `ha=left`, `va=top` in `annot_kws` is setting the text position relative to the tick locations, _not_ the position relative to the cell: note the annotations are now located with their left and top now aligned with the centre of the tick labels.

Comment: Quite right.  I add last link specially to clarify this behavior.

Comment: Also note that the labels in your second approach are not right: since the y locations go top to bottom, but your loop goes bottom to top, the labels are flipped vertically. (look at (4,3) and (4,1). The lighter of the two should show the label `1`, but instead it shows `27`

Comment: Yep but when you change `x` and `y` in cycle you may place a label in any desired place without values of `ha` and `va`.

Comment: I'm not talking about `ha` and `va` now. The labels in your second figure **do not** correspond to the data.

Comment: The labels in the second example are wrong. You'd see that when turning `annot=True` on in the second example and compare the numbers.

Comment: I think they're just flipped vertically.

Comment: @PaulH, yes, that's what I said about 4 comments up :)

Comment: Yep, data have to be reserved like now.